# yum to install fails on default empty server

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, yum

I used to download Fedora from site X, for example, but lately the site has not updated itself with new packages, therefore commands used to install any of those packages report back with errors as the packages required are not found on the specified server. I would like to learn how to change the default mirror URL inside my install Linux so that it can search freely anywhere the particular packages are available ? Is this possible ? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you give the repo you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The mirror used is stored in one of the files in /etc/yum.repos.d .  The exact file is going to depend on which repository you are actually using.  You can find a list of up to date Fedora mirrors at http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/